# In Rails, why there is a new Gemfile.lock when no bundle or bundle install was run? (and a new Gemfile timestamp too)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

It is very strange that all of a sudden, there is a new `Gemfile.lock` in my folder, even though I have not run `bundle` or `bundle install` or `bundle update` for a few days.

Also, I have merged in any changes and committed and pushed 1 hour ago, so this newly modified `Gemfile.lock` seems weird.

Also, the timestamp of `Gemfile` is just 1 minute before the timestamp (modification time) of `Gemfile.lock`, but I checked the Mercurial log and `Gemfile` was modified 3 days ago, and I pull any new changes 12 hours ago and there wasn't any change...

So why a new timestamp of `Gemfile`, and why is `Gemfile.lock` also modified?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running "bundle install" again, and see if it will change your Gemfile.lock file.