# When creating a new Rails application, why is there a Gemfile.lock file without running bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

And, how does the system install all the gems for the application without going through the bundle install process?

Note: This question is about the process of creating a ***new application***. Not the same question as [In Rails, why there is a new Gemfile.lock when no bundle or bundle install was run? (and a new Gemfile timestamp too)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711478/in-rails-why-there-is-a-new-gemfile-lock-when-no-bundle-or-bundle-install-was-r) .

Comment: In Rails 3.1 the `new` generator actually triggers `bundle install`. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Oh, really? OK, that makes sense. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gemfile.lock is a snapshot of the gems and their versions created when you run `bundle install`.  As explained in the *Checking Your Code into Version Control* section of the [Bundler rationale](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html):

> Gemfile.lock makes your application a single package of both your own
>   code and the third-party code it ran the last time so you know for sure
>   that everything worked. Specifying exact versions of the third-party
>   code you depend on in your Gemfile would not provide the same
>   guarantee, because gems usually declare a range of versions for their
>   dependencies.

Gems can be installed outside of bundler by [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) (e.g. `gem install gem_name`) but it's best to use [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/) which allows you to install separate versions of Ruby and manage individual gemsets for each application as explained in the [RVM best practices](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/).

Comment: I think the asker accidentally wrote "with" instead of "without" in the question.

Comment: No, I did mean `without going through the bundle install process`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `rails new <app>`, as part of setup it runs `bundle install` for you.